# what is the best way to deploy model project in tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, tomcat, maven-2

I have a multi module maven project containing a common model project and two web projects( 1 for the site uses jsf, and another is set of axis based web services used to collect data from the user)

When I deploy to tomcat I deploy it as 2 war files, the model project is compiled as jar and is included in both war files. 
Lately I have been getting a lot of permgen error. I am wondering if it is because I have these 2 war files each of which contains required libraries like HIbernate, Model project, and a bunch of other libraries needed for the individual projects.

My question is am I doing it right(I don't think I am)? and what is the best way to deploy a multiple web projects which depend on a common model project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the answer is to package it as EAR file instead of WAR as  you can package the jar files used commonly by the two web projects. only thing is I won't be able to use tomcat, time to look at Application servers will also try TomEE per David Blevins's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience of Maven, but I recently worked a lot with Java EE and in particular tomcat. I never got tomcat to work together with Eclipse (I have worked in Eclipse for Java projects since I started learning Java four years ago). I did a series of assignments and projects for a class at my school KTH. We had to use OpenEJB together with tomcat for the assignments but it was really messy to get it to work in Eclipse. So during the first assignments I just wrote code in a text editor and compiled from the terminal (OS X) and it was really ineffective.

However I got tip from a class mate that Netbeans had good support for Java EE. So I switched to Netbeans and used Glassfish and JSF. Switching to Netbeans proved to be a good choice. A really nice feature with Netbeans is that it can generate entity classes automatically based on your tables in your database. And then based on those entity classes Netbeans can generate JSF pages (controllers) for you. This makes it really fast and nice to develop Java EE projects. I followed this excellent guide:
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-crud.html

I hope this can help you! Sorry I couldn't give you a more precise solution.

Good luck!

Comment: Alexander, thanks for the answer. I have my application working but I am trying to reduce the number of libraries loaded along with my application to trim down bloat. I am looking for help with how to best package and deploy the application.

Comment: Hi, okay, but packaging and deployment is done automatically and - as far as I am concerned - effectively by Netbeans :). I hope you reach your goal :).

Comment: @AlexanderGeorgii-HemmingCyon Update on the Tomcat/OpenEJB stack.  We certified that as TomEE and it now works flawlessly in Eclipse.  Here's a video tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lr8pxEACVRI